# Configure Kong API gateway with service discovery

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin

I have a bunch of rest services. I want to have a Kong API Gateway implemented at the front. I d'ont want to go into Kong admin API and manually add all the exposed API. Can I take help of any service discovery implementation like eureka or consul to autoconfigure my APIs to Kong.

Comment: use kong service registry for service discovery functionality

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not. 
Kong's configurations are stored in postgres and updated through the admin API, you can write your own program to import.